# ERROR 1064 (42000): check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY "stormwind_rules"'

Tags: mysql

CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO "wp_user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "stormwind_rules";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY "stormwind_rules"' at line 1

Comment: Read Reference Manual for `GRANT` statement syntax carefully. It does not support `IDENTIFIED BY` clause on the version 8+.

Comment: Pls format the code nicely! It’s hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Create first followed by Grant

```
Create User "wp_user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "stormwind_rules"
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO "wp_user"@"%"
```